# Linux bridge over vlan is not working

Tags: linux, linux-networking, vlan, bridge, openstack

I have a Netgear Prosafe JGS524E switch where I have configured ports 1-10 to be a part of vlan 10(port 1 of the switch is connected to 192.168.1.0/24). In port 2, I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server where I wish to create multiple bridges. My configuration is like

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto eth0.10 
iface eth0.10 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device eth0

auto br-mgmt 
iface br-mgmt inet static
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_ports eth0.10
    address 192.168.1.13
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

I have installed all the packages required for setting up of bridges and vlan (bridge-utils vlan) and have added it to /etc/modules. I have verified that the 8021q module gets loaded. But because of some reason the I am unable to reach the gateway and the internet. Please help me find a possible solution to this problem. Please note that this setup is for deploying Openstack through Ansible.

Comment: Have you did a tcpdump on your `br-mgmt` interface to see eventual traffic ?

Comment: How is port 2 VLAN configured exactly?

Comment: When I did tcpdump it was showing this particular message:
`ARP , Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell`

Comment: I have put port 2 of the switch to VLAN id 10, and have connected a ubuntu 16.04 server to this port 2. I went to VLAN option in the switch and then to Port Based, and from there I created the VLAN ID and added the ports. PS: I am very new to vlan